# MySQL - On delete cascade issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

I have 3 table: A,B and C.
Relations are:

- A->B 1:1
- A->C 1:n

Table A is the main table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A` (
  `_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  ..........
  `_id_B` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Atable_Btable` (`_id_B` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_A_B`
    FOREIGN KEY (`_id_B` )
    REFERENCES `B` (`_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B` (
  `_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  ........
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `C` (
  `_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `_id_A` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Ctable_Atable` (`_id_A` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_C_A`
    FOREIGN KEY (`_id_A` )
    REFERENCES `A` (`_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I would to delete an entry on table A and I would delete **ON CASCADE** the entries from B and C.

How can I set my sql scripts to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that tables `A` and `B` are in `1:1` relationship but both have auto incrementing key. Instead you have an `A._id_B` field that I suppose is used to locate the corresponding (1:1) row in table `B`.

The standard approach would be to drop that `A._id_B` and in the other table (`B`), make the primary key **not** auto incrementing and also make it a `FOREIGN KEY` to the primary key of `A`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A 
( _id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  ..........
  PRIMARY KEY (_id) 
)
ENGINE = InnoDB ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS B 
( _id INT NOT NULL ,
  ........
  PRIMARY KEY (_id) ,                 --- B._id  is a primary key
  CONSTRAINT fk_B_A
    FOREIGN KEY (_id)                 --- and a foreign key
      REFERENCES A (_id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE                
 )
ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi its similar like following

. I have two tables:
article
commentary

Commentary has a foreign key to article.id, and of course, when deleting one article, I want all it's comments deleted as well. I've tried to do it as follows:

```
create table article (
id int not null auto_increment,
title varchar(80) not null,
subtitle varchar(80) not null,
content text not null,
author varchar(40) not null,
time datetime not null,

PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table commentary (
id int not null auto_increment,
article_id int not null,
title varchar(30),
content tinytext not null,
author varchar(40) not null,
email varchar(50),
ip varchar(16) not null,
time datetime not null,

PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (article_id)
    REFERENCES article(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This is according to documentation if I am not mistaken (a poster on the MySQL website
[with short description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html)

[This link may also useful to you](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to introduce a foreign key relationship from B pointing back to A (that is, B needs to include a column with A's id) for this to work. Then set your 'ON DELETE' clause for that relationship to 'ON DELETE CASCADE', and similarly for the fk_C_A constraint on C.